# Why is it believed that tool use among humans preceded spoken language?

Tags: history

I have read that human spoken language is 200k years old. This seems implausible because, for example, tool use is much older than this. Given that modern animals like parrots have the ability to use some portion of human languages, do we believe that ancient human ancestors had less mental capacity than modern parrots? Are there linguists who believe that spoken language might be much older and coincided with the making of tools (say, tools that required attaching two separate objects as opposed to simply shaping a single stone or piece of wood)?

Comment: Is your question about the sounds of language, or the grammatical systems that we call "language" as a whole? Parrots can imitate the sounds of human words but can't generally use morphosyntax.

Comment: @Draconis: My question is about generating sentences, not just imitating sounds. It is to me unquestionably true that parrots have the ability to use language, not just mimic.

Comment: @releseabe Linguists are in general extremely skeptical that any animals have language, to the extent that I'd say I think it's unquestionably false that parrots have the ability to use language. There's no archaeological evidence of when language first arose, which means this question is really just asking for speculations. I don't think it's a good fit for the site for that reason.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I realize that a long discussion about a now-dead parrot is not for this site, but if you watch videos of Alex the parrot and read about him, there can be no reasonable conclusion, assuming that the videos and research were not faked and/or cherry picked, that Alex answered spoken questions accurately about quantity and other attributes of objects such as color and shape using spoken English.

Comment: @releseabe Animals can communicate using signs/symbols, no question about that. But from what I've read about Alex I couldn't see any evidence that he, for example, demonstrated any use of syntactic recursion, which is often taken to be one of the essential features of human language. Maybe it could be argued that Alex could communicate at the level of a simplistic pidgin?

Comment: seconding @curiousdannii 's point about animal communication. There is plenty of evidence animals can acquire words, and use those to communicate. Evidence of animals being able to acquire _grammar_ is extremely lacking. Iirc bees are the only uncontroversial example and their communication has a lexicon is far too small for the sort of general communication human language is used for, and they have shown no evidence of an ability to acquire human lexemes

Comment: regardless, tool use is attested in a huge number of species. In particular, all hominins have been observed _making_ tools (rather than merely using existing objects as tools) suggesting that the origin of such tool use is before the divergence of the tribe. Otoh, humans are the only extant hominins shown to be able to acquire human language (as with the parrot, whilst apes have been shown to be able to acquire individual signs from sign languages fairly easily, there is no evidence of them using any consistent grammar with them, so they cannot reasonably be said to have human-like language)

Comment: @curiousdannii: As mentioned, Alex was a parrot. I am not sure "simplistic" is a very accurate word here. Did you mean "simple" instead?

Comment: @releseabe I said a [pidgin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidgin), not a [pigeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbidae).

Comment: @curiousdannii: ahh, how funny that I thought you meant another species of bird -- interestingly, while parrots are probably smarter, pigeons have shown themselves to be quite sophisticated, learning to make the right choice in the famous Monty Hall problem sooner than the average human.

Answer (score 6):

Following the argument of Fitch (*The evolution of language*), tool use is a shared trait of humans and chimpanzees, therefore it developed before the chimp-hominid split. Artifacts establish that stone tools have been around for 2 million years, which predates the development of spoken language. Speech is strictly a development of relatively modern humans. There are fossil suggestions regarding when speech capacity may have developed (increase in cranial capacity, development of the hyoid bone, middle ear bones that were capable of detecting frequencies in the range of human speech) in Homo heidelbergensis, dating from about 400 Kya. I have not heard of any linguist who holds the view that you suggest, however linguists generally are not technically competent to draw scientific conclusions in this area, instead, we rely on evolutionary biologists who hopefully understand a bit of the nature of language (as Fitch does).

Comment: Not all language is speech.

Comment: What did the OP ask?

Comment: I wasn't criticising your informative post, I was adding a comment about the implications that we might draw from our capacity for speech. Our capacity for language may not be dependent upon our ability to speak. And that seems like a relatively interesting observation. To me, and I thought maybe to others.

Comment: I don't understand the  "middle ear bones that were capable of  detecting frequencies in human speech". Are there animals that can hear but cannot hear the deliberately made sounds produced by other members of their species?